# I can't find my saved file in eclipse project directory

Tags: java, eclipse, filepath

I have a problem to find my file that is written correcty. I can read from it  but when I want to find it in my project directory it's not there..I tried to search for it in all my computer folders but it's not there. Only when I include apsolute path I find it in my project directory.

```
final String FILE_NAME = "test.dat";

//READ FILE
File readFile = new File(FILE_NAME);

if (readFile.exists()) {

System.out.println("file exsists...");
FileInputStream f_in = new FileInputStream(readFile);

   // Read object using ObjectInputStream
 ObjectInputStream obj_in = new ObjectInputStream(f_in);

// Read an object
   Object obj = null;

    try {
    obj = obj_in.readObject();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
     }

if (obj instanceof JsonObjectLoad) {

 jo = (JsonObjectLoad) obj;

  }
 obj_in.close();

}
else {
 jo = new JsonObjectLoad();

}

  jo.localities.add(loc);



//WRITE FILE
    File writeFile = new File(FILE_NAME);

    writeFile.createNewFile();

FileOutputStream f_out = new FileOutputStream(writeFile);

// Write object with ObjectOutputStream
ObjectOutputStream obj_out = new ObjectOutputStream(f_out);

// Write object out to disk
obj_out.writeObject(jo);
obj_out.close();
```

I found a path in C:\eclipse_ee\eclipse\test.dat... How can I change it?

Comment: sounds fishy. When you run a program in Eclipse, it runs it from the project's root directory. As you are not providing any path, it would read from the current directory (project's root) or from its classpath. I would suggest checking project's root directory and also all the classpath entries that you have added in Build Path. Try running the code form command line as well.

Answer (score 1):

Simply print the [absolute path](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getAbsolutePath%28%29) to check where it  exists? Create new file only when it doesn't [exits](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#exists%28%29) otherwise it will replace the existing one.

```
File writeFile = new File(FILE_NAME);
if(!writeFile.exists()){
    writeFile.createNewFile();
}
System.out.println(writeFile.getAbsolutePath());
```

**Note:** There is no need to calls `writeFile.createNewFile()` because `FileOutputStream` automatically create a new file if doesn't exist where you start writing in it.

---

If you want to open the file in append mode when file already exists and don't want to replace the existing content then use [FileOutputStream(File file,boolean append)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream%28java.io.File,%20boolean%29) constructor and pass `true` as append argument.

---

Use path relative to `src` folder of the project: (try any one)

```
// file that exists under resources folder parallel to src in your project
File file1 = new File("resources/xyz.txt");
System.out.println(file1.getAbsolutePath());

// file that exists under src/resources folder
File file2 = new File(getClass().getResource("/resources/abc.txt").toURI());
System.out.println(file2.getAbsolutePath());
```

Here is the project structure:

```
project root
           |
           |__src
           |    |
           |    |__resources
           |                |
           |                |__abc.txt
           |
           |__resources
                      |
                      |__xyz.txt
```

Comment: I found a path... It saves it in C:\eclipse_ee\eclipse\serialize.dat How can I change it?

Comment: but gives error with File file1 = new File("resources/abc.txt"); How to move it where I want?